# React and Redux: redirect after action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I develop a website with React/Redux and I use a thunk middleware to call my API. My problem concerns redirections after actions.

I really do not know how and where I can do the redirection: in my action, in the reducer, in my component, … ?

My action looks like this:

```js
export function deleteItem(id) {
    return {
        [CALL_API]: {
            endpoint: `item/${id}`,
            method: 'DELETE',
            types: [DELETE_ITEM_REQUEST, DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS, DELETE_ITEM_FAILURE]
        },
        id
    };
}
```

`react-redux` is already implemented on my website and I know that I can do as below, but I do not want to redirect the use if the request failed:

```js
router.push('/items');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually the better practice is to redirect in the component like this:

```
render(){
   if(requestFullfilled){
       router.push('/item')
   }
   else{
       return(
          <MyComponent />
       )
   }
}
```

Comment: there's a typo, it's called fulfilled

Comment: But what is requestFullfilled here? Is it only possible to get information about fulfilled request by setting a new state in redux or there is another clever way?

Comment: any state you update after an action is successful

Answer (score 20):

Definitely **do not** redirect from your reducers since they should be side effect free. 
It looks like you're using api-redux-middleware, which I believe does not have a success/failure/completion callback, which I think would be a pretty useful feature for the library.

[In this question from the middleware's repo,](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware/issues/53) the repo owner suggests something like this:

```
// Assuming you are using react-router version < 4.0
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

export function deleteItem(id) {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      endpoint: `item/${id}`,
      method: 'DELETE',
      types: [
        DELETE_ITEM_REQUEST, 
        {
          type: DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS,
          payload: (action, state, res) => {
            return res.json().then(json => {
              browserHistory.push('/your-route');
              return json;
            });
          },
        },
        DELETE_ITEM_FAILURE
      ]
    },
    id
  }
};
```

I personally prefer to have a flag in my connected component's props that if true, would route to the page that I want. I would set up the componentWillReceiveProps like so:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.foo.isDeleted) {
    this.props.router.push('/your-route');
  }
}
```

Comment: How you then reset back this flag `isDeleted`? If someone comes back to this component it's a big chance he will be automatically redirected without doing anything.

Comment: @Tomasz I had the same concern.  Wouldn't this get cumbersome if the new component would have to reset all state variables that are used in this redirection process  Seems unwieldy.

Comment: Jesus Christ - this answer is so amazing! I've spent so much time on such a simple issue. This solution is elegant and simple. Thank you so much @Yo Wakita!

Answer (score 14):

**The simplest solution**

You can use react-router-dom version **5+* it is actually built on top of **react-router** core.

**Usage:**

You need to import **useHistory** hook from react-router-dom and directly pass it in your actions creator function call.

**Import and Creating object**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const history = useHistory();
```

**Action Call in Component:**

```
dispatch(actionName(data, history));
```

**Action Creator**
Now, you can access history object as a function argument in action creator.

```
function actionName(data, history) {}
```

Comment: This works for me. Can you just use the history inside the action.js instead of passing in the action function? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @RoelJohn useHistory() is a hook, so we cannot use it outside a functional component.

Answer (score 2):

In the Redux scope must be used react-redux-router `push` action, instead of `browserHistory.push`

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

store.dispatch(push('/your-route'))
```

Comment: read this . you should add codes like this
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: react-router-redux is now deprecated. Check this out - https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

Answer (score 0):

I would love not to redirect but just change the state. You may just omit the result of deleted item id:

```
// dispatch an action after item is deleted
dispatch({ type: ITEM_DELETED, payload: id })

// reducer
case ITEM_DELETED:
  return { items: state.items.filter((_, i) => i !== action.payload) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a redirect function that takes in your redirect Url:

```
const redirect = redirectUrl => {
  window.location = redirectUrl;
};
```

Then import it into your action after dispatch and return it;

```
return redirect('/the-url-you-want-to-redirect-to');
```

Comment: this is generally bad practice, window.location will make the browser reload the whole app, unless it's intentional for some reason, it's usually not what we want...

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import {useEffect} from 'react';

const history = useHistory();

useEffect(()=>{
    // change if the user has successfully logged in and redirect to home 
    //screen
    if(state.isLoggedIn){
      history.push('/home');
    }
// add this in order to listen to state/store changes in the UI
}, [state.isLoggedIn])
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This is especially important when answering old questions (this one is 4 years old)  with existing answers. How does this answer improve upon the other 6?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to check for a state change in componentDidUpdate. Once your state has updated as a result of a successful redux action, you can compare the new props to the old and redirect if needed.

For example, you dispatch an action changing the value of itemOfInterest in your redux state. Your component [receives the new state in its props](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect), and you compare the new value to the old. If they are not equal, push the new route.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps: ComponentProps) {
  if (this.props.itemOfInterest !== prevProps.itemOfInterest) {
    this.props.history.push('/');
  }
}
```

In your case of deleting an item, if the items are stored in an array, you can compare the new array to the old.